# How can you create an excel from a serialized model in DJANGO REST FRAMEWOK to be consumed (downloaded)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Good afternoon I have a query how I could generate an excel of a serialized model in DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK to be consumed from a frontend (Angular). This excel I want to have the possibility that it has a filter, for example I want it to only bring me the records that have the P79COL01 equipment column in the property or property, in addition to other filters.

What I want is that from the front I give a button to download, I select for example that in the excel I bring all the files that in the property EquipoOrigen = P79COL01, and I make request and automatically generate the excel where only the records of according to the parameter that I just passed as a filter (Computer Source = P79COL01) of the serialized model Interfaces.

My Model Interfaces

```
class Interfaces(models.Model):

    id_interface=models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_EquipoOrigen=models.ForeignKey(Equipos,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='equipo_origen')
    id_PuertoOrigen=models.ForeignKey(Puertos,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='puerto_origen',null=True,blank=True)
    estatus=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    etiqueta_prtg=models.CharField(max_length=80,null=True,blank=True)
    grupo=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    if_index=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    bw=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    bw_al=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    id_prtg=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    ospf=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    id_EquipoDestino=models.ForeignKey(Equipos,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='equipo_destino')
    id_PuertoDestino=models.ForeignKey(Puertos,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='puerto_destino')
    ultima_actualizacion=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table='Interfaces'
```

My Serializer Model Interfaces

```
class InterfaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

# Las siguientes lineas me permiten agregan campos de otros modelos al modelo en cuestion que estoty serializando a traves de llaves foraneas.

#Se le agrega la propiedad de read_only=True para que el campo no sea editable.

    EquipoOrigen = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.nombre',read_only=True)
    PuertoOrigen = serializers.CharField(source='id_PuertoOrigen.nombre',read_only=True)
    LocalidadOrigen=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.localidad',read_only=True)
    CategoriaOrigen=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.categoria',read_only=True)
    EquipoDestino = serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.nombre',read_only=True)
    PuertoDestino = serializers.CharField(source='id_PuertoDestino.nombre',read_only=True)
    LocalidadDestino=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.localidad',read_only=True)
    CategoriaDestino=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoDestino.categoria',read_only=True)
    Vendedor=serializers.CharField(source='id_EquipoOrigen.vendedor',read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Interfaces
        fields=('id_interface','id_EquipoOrigen','EquipoOrigen','id_PuertoOrigen','PuertoOrigen','LocalidadOrigen','CategoriaOrigen','Vendedor','estatus','etiqueta_prtg','grupo','if_index','bw','bw_al','id_prtg','ospf','description','id_EquipoDestino','EquipoDestino','id_PuertoDestino','PuertoDestino','LocalidadDestino','CategoriaDestino','ultima_actualizacion',)
```

My ModelViewSet Interfaces

```
class InterfacesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset=Interfaces.objects.all()
    serializer_class=InterfaceSerializer
    pagination_class=PostPageNumberPagination
    filter_class=InterfacesFilter
```

```
class PostPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size=10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

#Funcion Para El Filtro del Modelo Interfaces.

class InterfacesFilter(filters.FilterSet):
# Lineas de Codigo para filtrar campos relacionados, es decir campo que estan en el serializador del modelo Interfaces a traves de Llaves Foraneas.
    # id_EquipoOrigen=filters.NumberFilter(lookup_expr='exact')
    EquipoOrigen=filters.CharFilter(field_name='id_EquipoOrigen__nombre',lookup_expr='contains')
    LocalidadOrigen=filters.CharFilter(field_name='id_EquipoOrigen__localidad',lookup_expr='exact')
    Vendedor=filters.CharFilter(field_name='id_EquipoOrigen__vendedor',lookup_expr='exact')
#Declarando el Meta    
    class Meta:
        model=Interfaces
        fields= ['EquipoOrigen','LocalidadOrigen','Vendedor']
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Do you want to know how to generate an Excel file, or do you want to know how to make it downloadable from a Django Rest Framework endpoint?

Comment: I think I was wrong in what I told you, I mean what I wish is that from the front I give it a button to download, I select for example that in the excel I bring all the files that in the EquipoOrigen property = P79COL01, and I make request and Automatically I generate the Excel where only the records are according to the parameter that I just passed as a filter (EquipoOrigen = P79COL01).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Openpyxl? https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/# It works great and it´s quite straightforward. I never tested it with the Rest Framework but I think It should work.

Here are the details about filter settings in a generated Excel file. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstable, you have to choose a directory in your project where you are going to store the files (I usually store them on `media` directory), and instruct **Django** where to find such directory:

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Then, ensure that your code stores the files in such directory:

**views.py** (in my case)

```
current_directory = settings.MEDIA_DIR
document.save(current_directory + file_name) # Here, save your document as your library requires to
```

After that, you only need an endpoint that returns the url to the document, like this:

```
return request.get_host()+settings.MEDIA_URL+file_name
```

When you send a `GET` request to such url, your file will download automatically.

**EDIT**

Before being able to download the file, you must:

1.- Be able to send `POST` requests from a form to a viewset through an endpoint. You must send the filter criteria to the viewset through such `POST` request. You must consult the documentation of your front end library to now how to do this.

2.- Be able to generate the resultset based on the filter criteria your viewset received along with the `POST` request (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/)

3.- Be able to generate an excel file, using a third party library (such as https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/).

4.- Apply what I recommended on the first post of this answer.

Comment: I think I was wrong in what I told you, I mean what I wish is that from the front I give it a button to download, I select for example that in the excel I bring all the files that in the EquipoOrigen property = P79COL01, and I make request and Automatically I generate the Excel where only the records are according to the parameter that I just passed as a filter (EquipoOrigen = P79COL01).

Comment: Will you have some documentation regarding point 1 using ANGULAR? Because I don't get much information.

Comment: Well, I am a backend engineer, so I am not an expert on frontend libraries, but being Angular a JS library, I think you should have no problem using a standard AJAX (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp), or using some other library like Axios (https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: friend could you give me a help how to capture in DJANGO or DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK what comes in a post application or endpoint, which I do not understand well, in this case example I have this url or endpoint that I place in the frontend to generate the download: http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_prtg/descarga/EquipoOrigen=P79COL01, by requesting a post, then I want to capture in the backend by means of a dress set that EquipoOrigen = P79COL01 to generate the excel filter and be able to download.

Comment: Pal, you have to do it through viewsets (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)